# Suffering, good people and Holy Quran

Tags: quran

I am still discovering the Quran, thus my question might look stupid.

From the Quran's perspective, why *good people* often *suffer* from awful *diseases* which are often *not related* to their *lifestyle* (ex: cancer)? Do pain and suffering among these *good people* is something covered somewhere in the Quran? Is there a reason to that since it could like some sort of *injustice*?

Thank you.

Comment: I won't call injustice: But a Islamic POV would be considering it as a assessment or test for their faith. But i would like to know if the **Q**uestion is *general* or has something to do with what you've read in Quran?

Comment: I'm looking for references or a starting point to understand the Islamic point of view on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TRIALS AND TESTS:-

Your question is not at all stupid but it is suited as to why Allah makes his loved servants suffer or put trial.
References to your question:-
HOLY QUR'AN
And surely We shall try you with something of fear and hunger, and loss of wealth and lives and crops; but give glad tidings to the patient, Who says, when afflicted with calamity: “To Allah We belong, and to Him is our return”: They are those on whom (descend) Blessings from Allah, and Mercy, and they are the ones that receive guidance. (Al-Baqarah 2:155-157)

In another verse, Allah Almighty says:

He Who created Death and Life, that He may try which of you is best in deed: and He is the Exalted in Might, Oft-Forgiving. (Al-Mulk 67:2)

Whatever misfortune happens to you, is because of the things your hands have wrought, and for many (of them) He grants forgiveness. (Ash-Shura 42:30)

Surah Hajj
22:11 And there is, too, among  befalls him, he is satisfied with Him; but if a trial assails him, he turns away utterly, [9] losing [thereby both] this world and the life to come: [and] this, indeed, is a loss beyond compare! [10]

HADITH (sayings and actions of the Prophet):-

Abu Huraira (RA) reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said: If Allah intends good for someone, then He afflicts him with trials.
Sahih Bukhari 5321

Mus’ad ibn Sa’eed reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said:
The servant will continue to be tried until he is left walking upon the earth without any sin.
Sunan At-Tirmidhi 2398

“…and be patient. Indeed, Allah is with the patient.” [al-Anfal 8:46].

Conclusion:- These test, sufferings, trials are to try us in our decisions and and strengthen our faith and bond with Allah. Every test you pass or succeed, you raise a level higher and closer to Allah. May Allah be with you!